# try and catch, 2 classes

Tags: c++

I have a function using `try-catch`. so I want use and another class to print out different kind of messages. What should I do?

I use namespace `std`. I'm new at this an not familiar with using namespace `std`. Please guide me thanks.

```
SparseException::SparseException ()
{ }

SparseException::SparseException (char *message)
{ }

void SparseException::printMessage () const
{ 
   // ... 
}

try
{
    //did some stuffs here.
}
catch (exception e)
{
    char *message = "Sparse Exception caught: Element not found, delete fail";
    SparseException s (message);
    s.printMessage();
}
```

Comment: btw, catch by reference, such as `catch (exception& e)` to avoid redundant copying.

Answer (score 3):

Derive your exception class from `std::exception` and override `what()`. Remove your function `printMessage` and implement (override):

```
virtual const char* what() const throw();
```

In C++11 this function has this signature:

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
```

Then your catch clause and printing of exception's reason can look like this:

```
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
  std::cerr << "exception caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: +1 I can hardly think of a reason why you should do anything except derive from exception classes out of the std library.

Comment: You might want to add to catch (const std::exception& ex) as you don't want to change the exception after it has been thrown. Also you can also catch (...) for all the exceptions you forgot.

Comment: catch(...) is often considered as evil

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are going to throw only your exception, you can simply do this:

```
SparseException::SparseException ()
{ }

SparseException::SparseException (char *message)
{ }

void SparseException::printMessage () const
{ 
   // ... 
}

try
{
    //did some stuffs here.
    //Possibly
    //throw SparseException();
    //or
    //throw SparseException("Some string");
    //Make sure you can throw only objects of SparseException type
}
catch (SparseException e)
{
    e.printMessage();
}
```

If the line with throw is executed, the result of try block will be terminated and the catch block will execute, where e is the object you have thrown.